# Problems with visualization classification_report

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trying plot classification report, but in my problem have a only 2 classes (0 and 1) and when I called the classification report, his output is it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ZPR.png)

My model is a LSTM with Glove embedding for sentiment classification, this is an architecture:

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_6 (Embedding)      (None, 55, 300)           68299200  
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_12 (Spatia (None, 55, 300)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_12 (LSTM)               (None, 55, 128)           219648    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_13 (LSTM)               (None, 55, 64)            49408     
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_13 (Spatia (None, 55, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 55, 512)           33280     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 55, 512)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 55, 64)            32832     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 55, 1)             65        
=================================================================
Total params: 68,634,433
Trainable params: 335,233
Non-trainable params: 68,299,200
```

Comment: Can you add shapes of your `y_pred` and `y_test` before passing it to the argmax function?

Comment: Did you check if `y_pred` only contains only two values `1` and `0` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your output from the `classification_report` to be a `dict()`, so that you can then read it as a pandas DataFrame via `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

display(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)).T)
```